# Downgrading CP version (Cumulative Patch) on some of the nodes of a jboss 4.3.0 installation

Tags: jboss, java

My scenario is a jboss 4.3.0 installation with several nodes. Some of the nodes are on CP08, and some are in - say - CP05.

Upgrading from CP05 to CP08 is a no-brainer using "jboss ON", according to the online manual:

> Applying JBoss Patches.
>
> https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/JBoss_Operations_Network/2.4/html/Basic_Admin_Guide/Applying_JBoss_Patches.html

My question is, is it possible going the reverse way: downgrading from CP08 to CP05? (And how would you do it!).

If not a detailed explanation, it would be helpful some pointers where I could find answers.

(If you are interested in the reason behind downgrading, it is because the production servers are on a lower CP version. Obtaining permission to operate on development servers is always easier.)

Comment: I might add, that JBoss EAP 4.3.0 version is equivalent to EAP 4.2.1 version with some minor additions.

Comment: Further investigation shows there is no non-hacking way of downgrading.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to transform your own comment in an answer (as it is).

Answer (score 0):

As there is no clean path to downgrade a jboss instance, a guess a more simple approach would do the trick:

Create a fresh new CP05 instance and redeploy apps. from CP08 instance.

(Ops, this is an opinion!)